# user define function with jQuery in noConflict mod

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that when user click on this div appendchild() function called.
this is html code

```
<div onclick="appendchild()">click me !</div>
```

this is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function appendchild() {
        //do something with jquery  
    }
});
```

I convert it to this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            function appendchild() {
                //do something with jquery  
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

but that not working
please tell me how can I define my function in jQuery noConflict().

Comment: Why are you using ready handler twice?

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers.

Comment: And ya, appendchild() function is not in global scope here. BTW, pseudo ready event remove handler once fired

Comment: my code working in jquery mode.my problem is that not working in jquery noConflict()

Comment: it is not important that appendchild() has a global scope. i can define it in a global scope.but i want to find out how i can define my function in jquery noconflict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69Nua/

make your HTML like this

```
<div class="clickme">click me !</div>
```

then you can `$(document).on` to bind `click` event

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickme", function () { 
    $(this).append("<span> hello </span>");
});
```

OR if you really like the function architecture. then you can do the following

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickme", function () { 
    appendchild($(this));
});

function appendchild(element)
{
    $(element).append("<span> hello </span>");
}
```

For Jquery NoConflict()

```
  var jq = $.noConflict();
   jq(document).ready(function () {
       jq(document).on("click blur change onmouseover", ".clickme", function () { // you can put as many event you want inside this ...
           appendchild($(this));
       });
   });
```

more on Jquery.noConflict() [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp)

Comment: It would be more beneficial if you were to add to this an explanation of why what he was doing was wrong.

Comment: my code working in jquery mode.my problem is that not working in jquery noConflict()

Comment: my problem is that i want to undestand how can I define my function in jquery no conflict

Comment: tank you for answer me.this example is only for click event can you tell me topically how can i define my function in noconfict ?

Comment: see my edit please... you can put as many event you want.. you can use the same technique for any other events...